# Restangular put method with extra route don't send data

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm wondering what's wrong with this snippet:

(my goal if send a put request to user/14/account with data to update of course)

```
.controller('UserAccountCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', 'user','User','Restangular',
        function($rootScope, $scope, $state, user, User, Restangular) {
            $scope.user = Restangular.one('user',14).get().$object;
            $scope.errors = null;


            $scope.save = function(){
               $scope.user.one('account').put();
            };
        }
    ]);
```

I've got a call to user/14/account but without data :(

### UPDATE

this seems to work

```
var user = Restangular.one('user',14).one('account');
```